# plotting time series data from a csv file in gnuplot returns an error

Tags: csv, charts, plot, gnuplot, time-series

I'm trying to plot time series data from a csv file but always get an error that says "all points y value undefined!"  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the following commands I issue

```
set datafile separator ','
set xdata time
set timefmt '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'               
set format x '%H:%M'
set autoscale y
set xrange ['07/01/2014':'07/10/2014']
plot 'data.csv' u 3:4 w lines
```

the data in the csv file looks like below

```
sensor name,server name,2014-07-01 20:11:48,16.44954,V,valuetype
sensor name,server name,2014-07-01 20:12:08,16.48951,V,valuetype
sensor name,server name,2014-07-01 20:12:18,16.53948,v,valuetype
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you've defined your `timefmt` in the gnuplot script versus how it is actually in the data file:

You will need to change `timefmt` so that it matches that in your data file

```
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

And then set `xrange` similarly. Following is tailored to the data you've provided. You may change the values to suite your complete data:

```
set xrange ['2014-07-01 20:11:00':'2014-07-01 20:12:20']
```

Comment: I didn't even catch the formatting, everytime I opened my file in excel it was always displayed in mm/dd/yyyy.  thanks for the answer.